# Right way of database migration

Tags: database, symfony, procedure

I am developing a Symfony2 App with MySQL Database. The old version of this Project based on .Net and MSSql.

Now i will migrate data from old project (MSSql Database) to MySQL Database, which have different relations.

I have following approach:

- Export tables as CSV from MSSql
- Import CSV with prefix "import_*" to the MySQL Database
- Write MySQL Procedures to do the migration /
- or write flat PHP to migrate the contents of "import_*" tables

What was the best way for this case of data migration? What do you recommend me?

Comment: How big is your database ? Number of tables ?

Comment: @coil the database have about 70-80 tables, but need to migrate only 5-6 tables with about 500-1000 rows in each table